# How can I use JavaScript on the client side to detect if the page was encrypted?

Tags: javascript, http, https

Is it possible to detect, on the client side, whether the user is using an encrypted page or not?

Put another way -- I want to know if the URL of the current page starts with http or https.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `window.location.protocol` to check if it is `https:`

```
function isSecure()
{
   return window.location.protocol == 'https:';
}
```

Alternatively you can omit specifying "window" if you don't have a locally scoped location.

```
function isSecure()
{
   return location.protocol == 'https:';
}
```

Comment: window. is the global scope and hence not needed, just a side-note.

Comment: didnt know about .protocol, simpler than my solution

Comment: jishi: it's a style issue, arguably the ‘window.’ makes it clearer where the property is coming from. Conceivably you could also have a local/closure variable called ‘location’, in which case direct access to the global would get hidden.

Comment: I like the clarity of fully specifying the variable, but I can see where others might go for the shorthand and use the global scope.

Comment: [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011220/1541397) should be used instead when possible, because this answer is inaccurate when there are problems with certificate.

Answer (score 11):

As google analytics taught me:

```
if ("https:" == document.location.protocol) {
    /* secure */
} else {
    /* unsecure */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Second method for newest browsers:

```
var secure = window.isSecureContext;
```

or just get isSecureContext:

```
if (isSecureContext) {
   ...
}
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts#Feature_detection#Feature_detection

Comment: A warning from the linked page: "Locally delivered files such as `http://localhost` and `file://` paths are considered to have been delivered securely."

Comment: I am seeing `window.isSecureContext == true` but the browser is saying "Not Secure" due to the certificate being invalid. Is there any way to check the page has the "closed lock" with no warnings?