# Testing for parent window protocol in Opera

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out the protocol used by a parent window in a child window.  If I use window.opener.location.protocol, it works in everything (IE8, FF3.5.5, Safari4.0.3, Chrome4) except Opera.  In opera i get:

```
message: Security error: attempted to read protected variable 'protocol'
```

This used to work fine in Opera, but I guess they changed it.  I am using Opera 10.10.  Is there any way to test for the protocol, or even determine if the parent window is the same location and protocol as the child?

Comment: What are the urls of the parent and child windows?

Comment: They are different the child window is http, and the parent is https.  But i just need a way to determine it without testing window.opener.location.protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only get the error when the protocols are different.

In other words:

```
var isParentSecure;
try {
    isParentSecure = window.opener.location.protocol === 'https';
catch(e) { isParentSecure = window.location.protocol !== 'https'; }
```

I haven't actually tested this.

Comment: This question has some details to back up location.protocol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282444/how-can-i-use-javascript-on-the-client-side-to-detect-if-the-page-was-encrypted