# Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, https, window.location

Is there any way to detect HTTP or HTTPS and then force usage of HTTPS with JavaScript?

I have some codes for detecting the HTTP or HTTPS but I can't force it to use `https:` .

I'm using the *window.location.protocol* property to set whatever the site is to `https:` then refresh the page to hopefully reload a new https'ed URL loaded into the browser.

```
if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
   window.location.protocol = "https:";
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: This is far more reliably (and efficiently) handled server side.

Comment: I think you are right. As an attacker using a MITM attack, I could just delete this code. So it offers only protection against passiv attacks.

Comment: The detection part is a duplicate of [How can I use JavaScript on the client side to detect if the page was encrypted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282444/how-can-i-use-javascript-on-the-client-side-to-detect-if-the-page-was-encrypted) from 2008.

Comment: @NeoDevlin a MITM attacker on http can replace a server side redirect as well

Comment: Exactly. In 2018, there is no excuse not to use HSTS. This is the only safe way to force HTTPS.

Answer (score 607, accepted):

Try this

```
if (location.protocol !== 'https:') {
    location.replace(`https:${location.href.substring(location.protocol.length)}`);
}
```

`location.href = blah` adds this redirect to the browser history. If the user hits the back button, they will be redirected back to the the same page. It is better to use `location.replace` as it doesn't add this redirect to the browser history.

Comment: Why `window` and not `document`?

Comment: @webjay see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2431375/228534 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098898/228534

Comment: Should the string comparison be `!==`?

Comment: @WesTurner It shouldn't matter either way. They're both always going to be strings. If one was a number or a boolean, then it might make a difference.

Comment: What about using location,protocol? Now a days everyone suggesting it.

Comment: instead of doing substring you can just use window.location.hostname

Comment: I like to use: `if (window.location.protocol == "http") window.location.href = "https" + window.location.href.slice(4);`

Comment: While this does work, it causes a page refresh upon entering the website for the first time. Not an elegant solution.

Comment: @daalbert you missed a colon. This works: `if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') { window.location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.slice(5); }`

Comment: @Zero3: I haven't tested myself, but I would expect that since he left out the colon in both cases, it would come out to the same thing. After all, he left out the domain name, but that makes no difference because it is the same thing for both protocols.

Comment: @zondo I'm afraid that is not how string equality works. It checks whether both strings are completely identical. So when `window.location.protocol` is `http:`, it will not be equal to `http`, and thus the code does not work as intended. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/protocol), then `window.location.protocol` includes the colon after the protocol name. Also note that the domain name is not stored in `window.location.protocol` at all, so it is not used in the comparison in any way.

Comment: `location.replace(url)` would be much better than `location.href = url` for this case. You don't want this redirection in the browser's history or the user hitting the back button just to get redirected again.

Comment: Should this answer not be using `window.location.` instead of directly `location.` It's both clearer syntactically and safer incase location is locally overridden. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709037/window-location-versus-just-location

Comment: It should be noted that future protocols may exist just like https did not exist at one point and is now standard. So checking that its not https and forcing to https is different than checking that its http and forcing to https (which is what the question asked too). Suppose some protocol exists in 2026 like httpz and is even more standard, and server rules auto route users to that, now we will be forcing them back to the older https protocol, unless we update our JS everywhere. Better to just check protocol = http then redirect to https. Safer for future

Comment: Works great in instances where the .htaccess or apache vhost methods for doing this are creating issues.

Answer (score 79):

[Setting location.protocol navigates to a new URL](http://developers.whatwg.org/urls.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes). No need to parse/slice anything.

```
if (location.protocol !== "https:") {
  location.protocol = "https:";
}
```

Firefox 49 has a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726779) where `https` works but `https:` does not. Said to be [fixed in Firefox 54](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328894).

Comment: `if window.location.href.match('http:') window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('http', 'https')` works on latest FF and Chrome.

Comment: `location.protocol = "https";` seems to work though in firefox 28

Comment: Crap that breaks the back button. Use `location.replace` instead.

Answer (score 26):

It is not good idea because you just *temporary* redirect user to https and browser doesn't save this redirect.

You describe task for web-server (apache, nginx etc) [http 301, http 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

Comment: agree. Forcing https on server is far more reliable

Comment: I could see it being used if preserving the hash value is important. It is not sent to the server and some browsers do not preserve it.

Comment: Here's a link to Set Azure Web Site for https only ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/01/07/https-only-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

Comment: Not necessarily true. There is a school of thought that 301 is the devil for caching reasons. http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

Comment: While it's true that it's generally not a good idea to do this client side, this is not what was asked. And you do not show how to do it, hence this is not an answer. Also, in these days of static webpages, often there is no way to do this server side (think Github pages), meaning you have to do this on the client. Still, you can help improve the search by adding canonical link tags to avoid people hitting the non-ssl version.

Answer (score 17):

```
if (location.protocol == 'http:')
  location.href = location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:')
```

Answer (score 16):

How about this?

```
if (window.location.protocol !== 'https:') {
    window.location = 'https://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
}
```

Ideally you'd do it on the server side, though.

Comment: it's missing the port

Comment: and search / query string also

Answer (score 12):

You should check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

Add this **meta** tag to your index.html inside **head**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Much more elegant solution when you do not have control of the code being sun on the page (html from a db for instance). We had a gravatar insecure connection and this solved everything.

Comment: Works great, with one minor caveat--on the very first load the index page is left on http and not reloaded until you navigate again. Tested in incognito mode. It was a problem for my single page front-end which was CORS blocked as it was not immediately on HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

Not a Javascript way to answer this but if you use CloudFlare you can write [page rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) that redirect the user much faster to HTTPS and it's free. Looks like this in CloudFlare's Page Rules:

[image]

Comment: I actually found this very useful, not for answering the question as framed, but for providing useful information about a possibly more reliable way for a SaaS service that does not offer always-on SSL.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">        
        if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
           window.location.protocol = "https";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It works. Is it a standard way to redirect? will it work in all browsers?

Answer (score 4):

I like the answers for this question. But to be creative, I would like to share one more way:

```
<script>if (document.URL.substring(0,5) == "http:") window.location.replace('https:' + document.URL.substring(5));</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The below code assumes that the variable 'str' contains your http://.... string. It checks to see if it is https and if true does nothing. However if it is http it replaces http with https.

```js
if (str.indexOf('https') === -1) {
  str = str.replace('http', 'https')
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This answer is related to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300906/check-if-a-string-starts-with-http-using-javascript/11300967

Answer (score 2):

Functional way

```
window.location.protocol === 'http:' && (location.href = location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:'));
```

Comment: I like it!! Double quotes are sexier to me like a HUG! Love ur answer

Answer (score -2):

Hi i used this solution works perfectly.No Need to check, just use https.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.location="https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length, window.location.href.length);
</script>
```

Comment: wont this refresh the page even if the protocol is https?

Answer (score -2):

I have just had all the script variations tested by [Pui Cdm](https://clientsportal.pui.org.uk/products-services/starter-account--49.html),  included answers above and many others using php, htaccess, server configuration, and Javascript, the results are that the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
function showProtocall() {
        if (window.location.protocol != "https") {
            window.location = "https://" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length, window.location.href.length);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
    showProtocall();
</script>
```

provided by [vivek-srivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007819/vivek-srivastava)
works best and you can add further security in java script.