# Making a function work in HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, https

I have this Javascript code I inherited from another developer. I am very new to Javascript.

The problem I'm having is that it won't work when the user is in HTTPS. Is there a workaround for this problem?

```
var tier1CategoryLink = "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/categories/";
    $("#as_Placeholder").load(tier1CategoryLink + " .SubCategoryList > ul", function(){
        $('#tier1').find('option').remove().end().append('<option>Make</option>');
        $("#as_Placeholder ul li").each(function(){
            var thisText = $(this).children("a").text();
            if ((thisText != "All Products") && (thisText != "Best Selllers") && (thisText != "Chromoly Flywheel Combo Sale") && (thisText != "New Arrivals") && (thisText != "On Sale") && (thisText != "Needs Categories")) {
                $("#tier1").append("<option value='" + $(this).children("a").attr("href") + "'>" + thisText + "</option>");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Well, does it "work" if `"http://"` is changed to `"https://"`? (The first step to solving a problem is to understand the problem.)

Comment: define "the user is in HTTPS"

Comment: you may want to use relative links (or absolute relative I think it's called). Basically, just do `/categories` instead of `http://.../categories`.  That way the http or https are automatically done (as long as you don't go from a non-secure to a secure page for example, in which case you do need to specify it). Just change the first line to `var tier1CategoryLink = "/categories/";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window.location to determine user's current protocol and adjust accordingly:

```
var tier1CategoryLink = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/categories/";
```

Or just use relative URL:

```
var tier1CategoryLink = "/categories/";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to say that you get a java-script error in the browser. And that is expected too. When the user is in https then you have to amend the java-script to include https. For eg your first line must look like this:

```
var tier1CategoryLink = "https://" + window.location.hostname + "/categories/";
```

**EDIT:** Moreover you can have a look at this to solve your issue. 
[Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to just use double slashes

```
var tier1CategoryLink = "//" + window.location.hostname + "/categories/";
```

Details in spec [Section 5.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)