# Do I need http instead of https on one domain in a multisite setup?

Tags: wordpress, vimeo

It seems that Vimeo doesn't work with https. We have a WordPress multisite on an hhtps where one of the sites has iframed Vimeo videos. There are links from other sites to the site with the videos. So, if someone links back to the site with Vimeo, the videos don't work.

I believe I need a redirect that will switch https to http on all addresses in that domain specifically, but not to the other domain/addresses. All the .htaccess code I have seen is for specific files, not for a specific domain. Or, is there another way to work around the Vimeo problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you explain more clearly question? What have you tried before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this before `# BEGIN WordPress` in htaccess as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)
and after modifying it a bit, you should get what you want.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-with-vimeo\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain-with-vimeo.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #wordpress multisite rules here
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: If it worked for you pls accept the answer and an upvote would be appreciated too. Thanks

Comment: perhaps OP just confirmed that this is a duplicate and the accepted answer works?

Comment: @hakre hmm.. well i guess so. I just made it more specific to his current situation. ^_^