# Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My website's page www.itcontractorsuk.com/contractor_mortgages.php has been indexed in https version in Google index, i.e. https://www.itcontractorsuk.com/contractor_mortgages.php

However, I have uninstalled SSL from my website, but Google has still kept the https version of the page in its index. So, when someone clicks on the https version, it gives 107 SSL error.

Is there a way I can write something in .htaccess file that redirects the https request to http, i.e. http://www.itcontractorsuk.com/contractor_mortgages.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Https to http redirect using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `R=301` to tell search engines to update their links. put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```