# Wordpress https to http Redirect exception htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

My whole wordpress website is redirected to https. But i want all the pages that follow the below pattern to be http. So it should be converted from

https://example.com/topic/introduction/
https://example.com/topic/history/

To

http://example.com/topic/introduction/
http://example.com/topic/history/

Here is the complete htaccess file, it has w3tc installed.

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^client-portal?$ /your-profile?settings=course-certificates [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which pattern you mean, but you could use [the code written here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000059/4383432), to redirect all https:// URLs to the respecting http:// URLs.

If you have a closer look at it, you will see, that also HTTP status code 301 ("Moved Permanently") is send, so search engines might not punish you for changing the URL.

**Edit:** Maybe this pattern match could do the job, see comment below.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www\.example\.com/topic/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: I dont want the whole website to be redirected to http, just the urls that have /topic/* in it.

Comment: I see. Maybe you can make a pattern match like this: Code posted above
But I am not really good in .htaccess and can´t try it right now.