# Xampp site won't load with SSL disabled

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I am attempting to disable HTTPS by redirecting it to HTTP on my XAMPP server via my `.htaccess` but I was unable to do so. I looked quite a bit when I found this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021747) for the same question. Since I have full access to my XAMPP, I went and edited the httpd-ssl.conf and commented out the the virutal hosts section but my apache refused to start after that. After that I commented out `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in my httpd.conf which allowed my apache to start but I still can't redirect HTTPS to HTTP. The page just keeps loading nonstop.

Here is what my `htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I think that the problem I am facing might be that I commented out the entire SSL file so here are the lines I tried to comment out in the `httpd-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
```

I also tried setting `SSLEngine off` and Apache started but I started getting `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when I tried to load the site.

EDIT: LOGS

Commenting out `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in `httpd.conf` results in `[ssl:warn] [pid 5440:tid 364] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]` in my error.log after I start Apache.

Commenting out the virtual hosts section in my `httpd-ssl.conf` results in no errors in error.log but I get this in my xampp-control:

```
[Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
[Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
[Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Setting `SSLEngine off` results in `[ssl:warn] [pid 2276:tid 388] AH01916: Init: (www.example.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!` in my error.log after I start Apache.

Comment: "Does not work" or "won't start" or "I got an error" does not help at all. _What does that mean?_ What happened? What error did you get? Error message serve a purpose: they show what the issue is. One should read them (and post them here).

Comment: Are you using Chrome to try and view the site?