# How to force change the URL from https to http, when a user leaves page

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

How to force change the URL from https to http, when a user leaves the https page by clicking on another page?

can you use htaccess? or javascript?

this is for a wordpress site.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: You can use a plugin, there are many available to do this. Or do you have to do it programmaticly?

Comment: I tried finding a plugin that is not out of date or has poor reviews but couldn't manage to do so. I did find one that forces https for certain pages, however, when you leave that page the entire website is now browsing on https. :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

add it to your .htaccess file. Hope this will help you.

for more refrence [visit forum >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)

Comment: It unfortunately conflicts with the pages that require https :/