# 404 Error on https version

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I removed SSL from my wp site, but some https version of pages are still indexed in google including home page for some keywords and when i visit these https pages it gives 404 error, is there any way to 301 redirect these https pages to http version ? Please help, it is effecting my site ranking as https version shows meta error in google results :- A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt , I tried editing htaccess but nothing helped.

Comment: Use Let's Encrypt instead ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your `.htaccess` which would accomplish redirecting all https to http (via https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000059/6019768)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But if you want to have more control over `https` for say `wp-admin`, check this link out [Redirect WordPress Front End](http://blackhillswebworks.com/2013/10/30/redirect-wordpress-front-end-https-urls-to-http-without-a-plugin/) for a function you'd add to your `functions.php`.

Comment: this is not working, i tried this earlier, it worked when moved to cloud from shared then it' stopped working ..