# Why does website not load after transferring to different hosting provider and switching from https to http?

Tags: html, dns, hosting, transfer

This might be a trivial problem, since I am quite new to programming. I have searched the web and stackoverflow for a solution, but I didn't succeed. If this question indeed has been raised and answered before, I am very sorry for creating a duplicate.

**The Problem:**
I have recently transferred the domain liaillustr.at from one hosting company to another. Everything else remained untouched. However, the site wouldn't load in Firefox, instead presenting me with an error ("the connection has timed out"). I then cleared the cache. Nothing changed - I still couldn't reach the site. Only after clearing the history, the website loaded.

**Additional information:** I am experiencing the same problem in Opera and Chrome. However, I do not have any problems reaching the site using IE or Edge. Since I do not use IE and Edge any differently to Chrome and Opera, I expect this to be resulting from browser specific differences.

**My Question(s):** What is the reason for my problem? How can I make sure, this website is displayed properly to people who have already been to it before the transfer?

Please forgive me if I am being unclear - I tried my best, but this is not my native language.

(I edited the title, since it missed important information)

Comment: You need to be more precise: did you transfer your domain from one registrar to another, or you changed DNS hosting provider, or you transferred your web site from one hosting provider to another, or all of it. Did your new provider give you any instructions (or maybe ip address)?

Comment: I can't access your domain and mxtoolbox.com reports that no A record exists.

Comment: @dusan.bajic: Thank you very much for your fast reply! Being precise is quite difficult for me, since I do not know many of the English terms, but I'll try my best. This is how I proceeded: I terminated my domain-contract with the old provider. Using the auth-code I was able to transfer the domain to my new provider (world4you.com), where I bought a domain+webhosting package. I received a mail from the "official registration and administration office for .at-domains" (nic.at) confirming the transfer. I uploaded the files and am now (after clearing history) able to load the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain is listed in [Chromium HSTS preloaded list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) which means that Chrome will always try to open it using https:// which is apparently not configured properly on your web server and therefore Chrome will fail.

Comment: This! You can only access that site by https in those browsers because of that and your new hosting solution only has a http version. You need to set up https. Why oh why do people use HSTS preload without understanding it? https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/ "I believe that some of these are time bombs, that even if you know how to set them up, could easily trip up the next person who looks after your website".

Comment: @BazzaDP To set the record straight: I shared the cost for a hosting solution with a friend. However, this friend sometimes made changes (such as introducing https) without first consulting with me. This was the main reason for me to move to a different hosting service. I would never have gone for https yet, since I am well aware that I understand far too little of it.

Comment: Due to my little knowledge and the urgency of the matter: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13000059/6299705) be a sensible solution for me? I will of course read up on this topic afterwards, since I hate doing things I don't understand.

Thank you both very much for your input! I will accept this answer once I got the problem fixed.

Comment: No. You HAVE to use https now. Tweet @lgarron to ask to be removed from preload list. It will take about 3 to 4 months from Chrome and no guarantees for the rest. Best to accept you are on https now (no bad thing!) and get it set up on this new domain.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry it happens sometimes because of localdns cache in our system but after some time it clears the cache itself so all would be able to see correct website.

Answer (score 0):

Once you transfer the domain from one registrar to another, one needs to take care of the following.

1]Login into Domain registrar control panel where you have transferred your domain.

2]Register name server there.

3]Enter your doamin name with http://intodns.com and fetch report and see that name servers are registered correctly.

4]Allow 24-48 hours time for global propagation.Enter your domain name into https://www.whatsmydns.net/ and verify global propagation.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correctly, I did 1] and 2]. 3] Looks correct to me... 4] According to whatsmydns.net liaillustr.at has perfect global propagation. But - and please correct me if I'm wrong - I believe this is besides the point, since I can reach the website perfectly fine with other browsers or after clearing the history.

Comment: For IP 81.19.145.67(liaillustr.at), global propagation is yet to complete for country like France, Canada. Hence you need to wait.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. When I checked earlier (using your link) "liaillustr.at" had perfect global propagation - now it shows a red X for India. I didn't know this is a back and forth process. However, my argument remains: While I can't reach the website using one browser, I can reach it using another browser on the same exact machine using the same connection. Also I can make the browser load the site by clearing its history. Hence this problem can't have anything to do with propagation, can it?

Comment: There are various reasons behind not loading up website from differnet browsers. Follwoing are possible reason behind.

1]Your browser is loading the webpage from its internal cache.
2]Your browser has a site blocking extension installed.
3]Your router needs a hard reboot
4]Your Windows host file has an exception list which is permanently blocking access to some websites from every other browser e.g Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera or Safari

Try following command and check :
ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: Thank you very much for all this input. I will have to look into this later :/