# How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using this htaccess code to redirect my https terrafic to http
when we using this simple code to do this redirect,every things fine but it break sites search engine link.the site have visitor from google to this link domain.com/search/?q=jim 
and convert it to 
domain.com/search/?q= 
and jim keyword is losting.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^source/(.*)/(.*)$ source.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/?$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^not-found$ notfound.php [G,L]
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^lasttagmap.xml$ lasttagmap.php
RewriteRule ^randtagmap.xml$ randtagmap.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^categories-sitemap.xml$ categories-sitemap.php
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Https to http redirect using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)