# How do I disable https on my webserver using Plesk?

Tags: php, server, centos, plesk

I've got a CentOS server running Plesk 17, when I disable SSL/TLS Support in the hosting settings for my webisite, the document root changes to `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs` instead of staying with the one set `/var/www/vhosts/example.org`.

I'd like to disable completely https and redirect everything to http, does anyone know how to accomplish such a task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually you can't redirect from HTTPS to HTTP when HTTPS is disabled.

When you disable HTTPS for `domain.tld` and you trying to open `https://domain.tld` this request will be catch by Default Virtual Host which document root is `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs`

Yes, you can place in this document root [.htaccess with redirect rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess) but any user will see SSL Certificate Error first and in most of the cases will not continue to open such site.

To perform redirect from HTTPS to HTTP domain should have enabled HTTPS with valid SSL certificate, only in this case you can redirect user to HTTP.