# issues width htaccess redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect http to https by .htaccess
But it does not work some where!

This is my domain: www.amirforsati.ir

When i use http like http://www.amirforsati.ir it redirects to **https**

When i use http like http://www.amirforsati.ir/want it does not redirect to **https**

My apache .htacces code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^amirforsati\.ir [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.amirforsati.ir/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^136\.243\.80\.209
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.amirforsati.ir/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13000059/3933634 ? `RewriteEngine On` - `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` - `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: @Liberateur this is an answer for Https to http redirect using htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^want.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000059/3933634 (inverse)**

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all requests to https, I use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

Comment: i changed my code to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%/$1 [END,QSA,R=permanent]` but still does not work