# How to change https to http in url by html/php code?

Tags: http, https

Actually, I didn't get SSL certificate till now, But when searching my website in search engines, its shows with https in URL. when clicking that link, it takes to error page since I didn't have SSL certificate.So I want to change that slug from https to HTTP. But I don't know where to change in my Cpanel. Is there anybody having a solution for my problem? please, let me come out from my problem.

Comment: Which web server are you using? Nginx, Apache or something else?

Answer (score 0):

you should add the following rewrite rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:
```

If you want more refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)

Comment: Thank you lalith kumar, just i tried ur suggestion, but now also i am having the same issue? is there any other solution?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: is that helped you?

Comment: I referred that questions and used all those solutions, but still it's telling that "your connection is not private".@lalith kumar

Comment: check these steps: http://www.zerodollartips.com/your-connection-is-not-private-chrome/

Comment: now its saying that "Sample "Hello, World" Application

This is the home page for a sample application used to illustrate the source directory organization of a web application utilizing the principles outlined in the Application Developer's Guide.

To prove that they work, you can execute either of the following links:

To a JSP page.
To a servlet." @lalithkumar