# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS with query Get not working correctly

Tags: server

HI have some trouble to find solution that will redirect my page from link:
http://example.org/100
to 
https://example.org/index.php?id=100

This is my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}
```

It works correctly only when you use full page address with **https** (https://example.org/100)

**I find solution on my problem:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off'">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</If>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Https to http redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)

Comment: Unfortanly no because I need to redirect from http to https (whitch work fine) except part that convert query to ?id=100

Comment: Finely I find solution that work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find solution of my problem:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off'">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</If>
```