# What is the code to be added to Redirect from http to https in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

What is the code to be added to Redirect from http to https in .htaccess file?

here is the existing code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/NextNext/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

awaiting your help..

Comment: Please check for existing answers before asking your question. Look into the "Related" section on the right hand side of this page. I am sure you will find what is needed. For example that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule after RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```