# I want to redirect to https if anyone hits URL with http in Code Igniter PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, https

I want to redirect to https if anyone hits URL with http in Code Igniter PHP.
I am using this htaccess code. Help me with this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Add or Correct the htaccess code.

Comment: you do not redirect anything at the moment, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rest of htaccess
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here you can read some more about redirect http to https
[Https to http redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)