# Apply https on specific pages rather than whole website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have applied http and https in my local website through IIS. When I load my 1st page through https. And on the button click I call the javascript function to navigate to the other page i.e.

```
function redirect() {
            window.location("Page2.aspx");
        }
```

The protocol remains the same. Why is that so? And how can I apply https on specific pages of my website?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do that?

Comment: Well, mywebsite contains some payment option which is a requirement from client.

Comment: I was wondering why you would not want to use HTTPS all through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this,

```
window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
```

I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4723302/1172872

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTTPS all through and force all your users to use HTTPS, you can use URL Rewrite extension from  Microsoft for IIS. you can find it here http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Using URL rewite, it can be as simple as setting a rule in that so that all users are redirected to HTTPS irrespective of what they try to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex.

```
url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
```