# How to make URL Https through script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i facing problem to changing my URL from HTTP: to **Https**: through, Kindly share any idea or solution would that i able to change.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)

Comment: You'll need to buy an SSL Certificate.

Comment: have you tried using htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You'll need to buy an SSL Certificate. After that you can change url http to https for security.

I have given some website url which discribe, how to setup ssl certificate on server.

[How to Add SSL and HTTPS in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/)

[Definitive Guide to WordPress SSL](http://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-tutorial/definitive-guide-wordpress-ssl-setup/)