# Convert all http:// to https:// using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to covert links in src tags to `https://`. More accurately Youtube iframes. For example:

```
<iframe width='650' height='365' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/y9kBixgYKzw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried the  below code with no luck:

```
function RedirNonHttps() {
    if (location.src.indexOf("https://") == -1) {
        location.src = location.src.replace("http://", "https://");
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="RedirNonHttps();">
```

Can someone point me out the correct way to do this?

Comment: Doing this in JS is too late in the process as the request to the `http://` URL will already have been made. You need to make the change directly in your source code, or on the server before the HTML is served to the client

Comment: Just use `<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/y9kBixgYKzw" …>` in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the example below show how it would work. Loop the elements by `each` and replace the source tag, as in your code:

```
$("iframe").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("http://", "https://"));
});
```

But keep in mind, this might be to late. The frames may be already loaded over `http`. As pointed out before, you have to do it on server side to be sure the content will be loaded over `https`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to change the protocol of the URL in the iframe source? Or trying to redirect the incoming request to the HTTPS counterpart?

If it is the latter, you may want to try a solution like this:
[Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)

```
if (window.location.protocol != "https:")
    window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
```

You could run this in your head Javascript.

If you are trying to change the source of the iframe, I believe you will run into the issue that eisbehr has explained. That is, the external source has already loaded over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "https://" with just "//"

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/y9kBixgYKzw"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
if (location.protocol != 'https:')
{
 location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
}
```