# How to switch from http to https client side

Tags: javascript, browser, https

How to switch from http to https in a client side script. Do not change the URL **otherwise**. It should do nothing in https. The server replies the same to http and https. I need the rest of the Original URL to stay intact.

```
http://example.com --> https://example.com
http://example.com/a --> https://example.com/a
http://example.com/b --> https://example.com/b
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. HTTPS is for communicating securely with the server. There's no way to switch to HTTPS on the client side without changing the URL to a https:// one and making a new request to the server. That's the whole point of the exercise

Comment: What about simply taking the _current_ location and replacing `http` by `https`?

Comment: Who do that _client-side_? What's the point? Just return a redirect from the server.

Comment: Cannot change the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript window.location.href property to reload page with https url

```
// current url: http://example.
if(window.location.href.substr(0,5) !== 'https'){
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('http', 'https');
} // new url: https://example.
```

Comment: how to keep the rest of the URL the same ?

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: What happens when it is already on https ?

Comment: @WalleCyril The `if` statement ensures the redirect is only executed if the protocol is not https.