# How to redirect web page from http> https with Parameters & #reference

Tags: javascript

If I want to redirect   http://url  >  https:/url
like:  http://example.com?param=value#bookmark > http**s**://example.com?param=value#bookmark

I see how I can redirect with javascript but the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage/506004#506004)  leaves out the ?params and #bookmark.

What's a good way to redirect and retain the whole URL?

Comment: A better solution might be to just configure a redirect at the domain level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (window.location.protocol == "http:") 
    window.location.href = "https" + window.location.href.slice(4);
```

or just replace

```
if (location.protocol == 'http:')
  location.href = location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:')
```