# How to check URL contains http using JQuery and RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I check and add http (if it does not exist) in given url using jQuery and RegEx?

I tried the following:

```
jQuery("#text_box_url").blur(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val()) {
        if(jQuery(this).val().match(/~^(?:f|ht)tps?:/))
            jQuery(this).val("http://"+jQuery(this).val());
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282444/how-can-i-use-javascript-on-the-client-side-to-detect-if-the-page-was-encrypted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/dYbfY/2/

```
$("#text_box_url").blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var val = input.val();
  if (val && !val.match(/^http([s]?):\/\/.*/)) {
    input.val('http://' + val);
  }
});
```

**Update** a solution that leaves all values with a scheme untouched: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/c6akr9y2/

Comment: just what i was looking for!

Comment: what if the url is something like this `ftp://example.com`? Try it out

Comment: @nmargaritis true, it was an "example" not a solution as the answer pointed out. I've added an updated fiddle that leaves any value with a scheme untouched.