# jquery - adding `http://` to string if not present

Tags: jquery, regex, laravel, laravel-5, prefix

In my laravel app I process an external URL provided by user. Sometimes user would paste it without the `http://` prefix.
UI have used this question's answers:
[How to check URL contains http using JQuery and RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672712/how-to-check-url-contains-http-using-jquery-and-regex)

I tried to use these instructions

```
var lnk = $('#confirmation_URL').val();
var lnk2 = $('#confirmation_URL').val();

//adding http if not present
// if (lnk && !lnk.match(/^.+:\/\/.*/)) {  // produces jQuery error
if (lnk && !lnk.match(/^http([s]?):\/\/.*/)) { // produces jQuery error

   var lnk = $('http://' + lnk2);
   console.log( "prefix http added successfully" );
}
```

When pasting an URL, I get this error:

```
jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrationsga.error @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2ga.tokenize @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2ga.select @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2ga @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2n.fn.extend.find @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2n.fn.init @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2n @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ dodaj:1460n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

#### what i tried

The error pops out in console for both jQUery 2.14 and 3.0beta1
Just to test for silly mistakes and exclude potential causes (such as jQUery affecting the original variable) , I created two variables with identical content: `lnk` and `lnk2`.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
$('#confirmation_URL').keyup(function () {
        if (  ($(this).val().length >=5) && ($(this).val().substr(0, 5) != 'http:') && ($(this).val().substr(0, 5) != 'https') ) {
            $(this).val('http://' + $(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I simplified it: `        if (  ($(this).val().length >=5) && ($(this).val().substr(0, 4) != 'http')  ) {
                                $(this).val('http://' + $(this).val());
                                console.log('prefixed successfully');
                            } else {
                                 console.log('already prefixed');
                            }` 
But now upon pasting a link without `http` the IF  condition always execudes the part which SHOULD be executed when link has a `http`

Comment: I just tried to reverse the IF condition, but I got `http://http://` as an output. Funny, but despiriting. Any guesses?

Comment: OK. This code finally worked: `                            var lnk2 = $('#confirmation_URL').val();
                            if (  ($(this).val().length >=5) && ($(this).val().substr(0, 4) == 'http')  ) {
                                 console.log('already prefixed');
                            } else {
                                $(this).val('http://' + lnk2);
                                console.log('prefixed successfully');
                            }
                            var lnk = $(this).val();`
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
var lnk = $('#confirmation_URL').val();
var lnk2 = $('#confirmation_URL').val();

//adding http if not present
// if (lnk && !lnk.match(/^.+:\/\/.*/)) {  // produces jQuery error
if (lnk && !lnk.match(/^http([s]?):\/\/.*/)) { // produces jQuery error
   // Here produces error actually
   // lnk = $('http://' + lnk2);

   lnk = 'http://' + lnk2;
   $('#confirmation_URL').val(lnk);
   console.log( "prefix http added successfully" );
}
```

Updated, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: this solution produces `Uncaught TypeError: lnk.val is not a function`. I have also tied `$(lnk).val('http://' + lnk2);` and other variants, but to no success.

Comment: Ok, problem solved by Anbarasi's workaround. Thank you for your attempt!

Comment: It seems that you are mixing jQuery objects and strings, `$('#confirmation_URL')` is a jQuery object, while `'http://' + ...` is a string, `$('http://' + ...)` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is what I wrote under Aminah Nuraini's solution. I know it doesn't make sense. How transform the jQuery object into a string?

Answer (score 1):

Try create RegExp object first

```
regex = new RegExp('^http([s]?):\/\/.*')
if (lnk && !regex.test(lnk)) { 

   lnk.val('http://' + lnk2);
   console.log( "prefix http added successfully" );
}
```

Comment: your solution seems to be a php code. Are you sure I can youe your snippet to define a RexExp in jQuery?
Anyway, I still get `Uncaught TypeError: lnk.val is not a function`

Comment: I googled and it was for jQuery. Reading your error, it means the error is not on the regex

Comment: My understanding is that the pair `'http://' + lnk2` should be both a text string, but somehow they don't. Still no idea how to fix it. 
Check out the @Anbarasi solution - within it now the problem is that the IF condition is reversed.

Comment: Ok, problem solved by Anbarasi's workaround. Thank you for your attempt!